# AWS: intentHandler.call() in Alexa skills template cancels out preceding function call

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, iot, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to publish to an IoT topic from a Lambda function, which is triggered from an Alexa skill. In the Lambda function, I'm doing this IoT publish:

```
var params = {
  topic: 'testTopic',
  payload: new Buffer('test message'),
  qos: 1
};

iotData.publish(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log('ERR: ', err); // an error occurred
  else if (data) console.log('DATA: ', data);  // successful response
});
```

If I run this code (and this code only) in a Lambda function, it works fine. But if I put the params and the publish function in the onIntent function of the Alexa Skill template, and put that in a new Lambda function, it doesn't work. (Both Lambda functions have the same configuration and policies.)

If I comment out intentHandler.call(), then iotData.publish() does run, so it appears the the intentHandler call is cancelling it for some reason I don't understand.

```
onIntent: function (intentRequest, session, response) {
  var intent = intentRequest.intent,
      intentName = intentRequest.intent.name,
      intentHandler = this.intentHandlers[intentName];

  if (intentHandler) {
    console.log('dispatch intent = ' + intentName);

    var params = {
      topic: 'testTopic',
      payload: new Buffer('test message'),
      qos: 1
    };

    iotData.publish(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log('ERR: ', err); // an error occurred
      else if (data) console.log('DATA: ', data);  // successful response
    });

    intentHandler.call(this, intent, session, response);
  } else {
    throw 'Unsupported intent = ' + intentName;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be related to the Lambda function context. `intentHandler.call()` calls the intent in question, which in turn calls `context.succeed()`. I'm assuming this means the Lambda function finishes running before the `iotData.publish()` call can be executed, because when I put the `intentHandler.call()` in the callback for `iotData.publish()` like this, everything works fine:

```
onIntent: function (intentRequest, session, response) {
  var intent = intentRequest.intent,
      intentName = intentRequest.intent.name,
      intentHandler = this.intentHandlers[intentName];

  if (intentHandler) {
    console.log('dispatch intent = ' + intentName);

    var params = {
      topic: 'signals',
      payload: new Buffer(intentName),
      qos: 1
    };

    iotData.publish(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else {
        console.log(data);           // successful response
        intentHandler.call(this, intent, session, response);
      }     
    });
  } else {
    throw 'Unsupported intent = ' + intentName;
  }
}
```